# Efficiently merging a large number of pyspark DataFrames

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to perform dataframe union of thousands of dataframes in a Python list. I'm using two approaches I found. The first one is by means of [for loop union](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/faq/append-a-row-to-rdd-or-dataframe.html) and the second one is using [`functools.reduce`](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11356/merging-multiple-data-frames-row-wise-in-pyspark). Both them work well for toy examples, however for thousands of dataframes I'm experimenting a severe overhead, probably caused by code out of the JVM, sequentialy appending each dataframe at a time (using both merging approaches).

```
from functools import reduce  # For Python 3.x
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

# The reduce approach
def unionAll(dfs):
    return reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, dfs)

df_list = [td2, td3, td4, td5, td6, td7, td8, td9, td10]
df = unionAll(df_list)

#The loop approach
df = df_list[0].union(df_list[1])
for d in df_list[2:]:
    df = df.union(d)
```

The question is how to perform this multiple dataframe operation efficiently, probably circunventing the overhead caused by merging dataframes one-by-one.

Thank you very much

Comment: OP, please let me know how useful `pairwise_reduction` is for your actual dataframes.

Comment: Thank you very much @coldspeed your suggestion resulted much faster, however the memory oveehead persists.. for large number of dfs the memory crashes. can you help me with that?

Comment: I would suggest setting a checkpoint dir. See https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-rdd-checkpointing.html

Answer (score 8):

You are currently joining your DataFrames like this:

```
(((td1 + td2) + td3) + td4)
```

At each stage, you are concatenating a huge dataframe with a small dataframe, resulting in a copy at each step and a lot of wasted memory. I would suggest combining them like this:

```
(td1 + td2) + (td3 + td4)
```

The idea is to iteratively coalesce pairs of roughly the same size until you are left with a single result. Here is a prototype:

```
def pairwise_reduce(op, x):
    while len(x) > 1:
        v = [op(i, j) for i, j in zip(x[::2], x[1::2])]
        if len(x) > 1 and len(x) % 2 == 1:
            v[-1] = op(v[-1], x[-1])
        x = v
    return x[0]

result = pairwise_reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, df_list)
```

---

You will see how this makes a huge difference for python lists.

```
from functools import reduce 
from operator import add

x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]] * 1000

%timeit sum(x, [])
%timeit reduce(add, x)
%timeit pairwise_reduce(add, x)

64.2 ms ± 606 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
66.3 ms ± 679 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
970 µs ± 9.02 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

sum(x, []) == reduce(add, x) == pairwise_reduce(add, x)
# True
```

Comment: is there a df.union syntax version of this that cab work with methods?